# Smooth horizontal scroll bound to mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

Here is a working example of horizontal scroll with mousewheel, but it does not scroll smoothly. By smoothly I mean like ordinary vertical scroll in Firefox or Opera.

```
$(function() {
    $("html, body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

(http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs)

I've made a live demo to demonstrate this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Dw4Aj/

I want this scroll to work like the vertical one, both with mousewheel and smoothness.

Can someone help me?

Comment: create a live demo that replicates issue in jsfiddle.net

Comment: here is it! [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw4Aj/)

Comment: Possibly unrelated, I logged the `delta` variable scrolling on a MacBook trackpad (no mouse), and it proved pretty unreliable. Conduct your own tests and determine if that might be the weak link of this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to leave this here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dw4Aj/19/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("html, body").mousewheel(function(e, delta) { 
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollLeft: '-='+(150*delta)+'px' }, 200, 'easeOutQuint');
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Comment: This isn't working on Chrome 46. Made small changes but here is an updated version that it's working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dw4Aj/338/

Answer (score 3):

Smooth scrolling is a browser specific feature.

If you want something that works on all of them then you need to do it on your side.
There are multiple implementations of smooth scrolling for jQuery.

And actually you may even need so called kinetic scrolling. If so try [jquery.kinetic](http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/)

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want, even not close. I just want horizontal scroll to work like the original one vertical scroll in Firefox or Opera.

Comment: Since you're doing it programatically, it most likely won't work like the native controls.

Comment: @Vladimir Mikhalev As I said smooth scrolling is a browser specific feature. Google Chrome for example does not use smooth scrolling at all. So if you want to see smooth scrolling there and in all others and in the same manner you have to implement this manually or use some existing library for that.

Answer (score 2):

1st i think about it is to remember last scroll event timestamp, play with easing function, to get good result http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Dw4Aj/13/

```
$(function() {

    $("html, body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        var mult = 1;
        var $this = $(this);
        if (event.timeStamp - $this.data('oldtimeStamp') < 1000) {
            //calculate easing here
            mult = 1000 / (event.timeStamp - $this.data('oldtimeStamp'));
        }
        $this.data('oldtimeStamp', event.timeStamp);
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta) * mult;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Did you perchance test your demo in chrome?  Not working for me.

Comment: None.  The only thing I can really determine is that scrollLeft sometimes doesn't get set.

Comment: It's working but very glitchy. I think that right answer is to use .animate to make it work properly.

Comment: Hm, I checked with FF and chrome, works fine for me, but it may be because of my  mouse,

Comment: I would not suggest to use animation() you will take some new problems  with it (animation stop/start, how to handle new events during animation, how to scroll by minimal possible delta)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your function in conjunction with .animate()

```
$(function() {
    $("html, body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        var scroll_distance = delta * 30
        this.animate(function(){
           left: "-=" + scroll_distance + "px",
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I just actually did this myself and it works. I created an instagram feed on the web application that I created, and the other plugins that I was using were breaking all too often:

```
$('#add_instagram').on('mousewheel', function(e,d){
    var delta = d*10;
    $('#move_this').animate({
        top: "-=" + delta + "px"
    },3);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: does not work, says "syntax error" here:           left: -= (delta * 30);

Comment: Try putting that in quotes: "-=(delta*30)px"

Comment: Not working both ways, now it says "animate is not a function"

Comment: Ok... Do $(this) instead of just "this"

Comment: Sad, but I have nothing. Here is your script injected http://jsfiddle.net/Dw4Aj/17/

Comment: Here's a plugin that I created today. This might help: https://github.com/bjoshuanoah/scrollThis.js

Answer (score 0):

I found other nice solution - to use wrapper, so you scroll absolute to same position as you would to scroll vertical, it works if you just need scroll, no text selection or other(may be can work arounded, but i tired)

```
$(function() {

    var scroll = $('.scrollme');
    var h = scroll.parent().height();
    var w = scroll.parent().width();
    var t = scroll.offset().top;
    var l = scroll.offset().left;
    var vertscroll_wrap = $("<div>").height(h).width(10000).css('position', 'absolute').css('top', t).css('left', l).css('z-index', 10000).css('opacity', 0.5).css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    var vertscroll = $('<div>').height(10000).css('width', '100%').css('opacity', 0.5);
    vertscroll_wrap.append(vertscroll);
    $('body').append(vertscroll_wrap);
    vertscroll_wrap.height('100%');
    vertscroll_wrap.scroll(function() {
        $(scroll).parent().scrollLeft($(this).scrollTop());
    });


});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Dw4Aj/16/

i made another sample, now without wholescreen wrapper, and possibility to select
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DcyWD/

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
```

to this:

```
this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to utilize the browser built in scroll behavior, by using simply scrollBy:

```
const target = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever')[0];
target.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    target.scrollBy({
    left: event.deltaY*0.5,    
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

})

It is a bit sloppy when you scroll more before the browser finished the smooth scroll (as smooth scrolling takes some time to finish the "animation"), but for some scenarios it does the job.

You can also achieve the same essentially by settings the css property `scroll-behavior: smooth`, and then explicitly setting `target.scrollLeft = ...` on the element.
Both approaches essentially use the bult-in scroll implementation of the browsers (except Safari and IE10 maybe, as those don't support this smooth behavior at all to date)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the stuck when re-scrolling to the end of the previous scroll.

pure js.

```
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever')[0];
let sumDelta = 0
let startLeft = 0
let targetLeft = 0
el.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    if (el.scrollLeft === targetLeft) sumDelta = 0
    if (sumDelta === 0) startLeft = el.scrollLeft
    sumDelta -= e.deltaY
    const maxScrollLeft = el.scrollWidth - el.clientWidth;
    const left = Math.min(maxScrollLeft, Math.max(0, startLeft - sumDelta));
    targetLeft = left
    el.scrollTo({left, behavior: "smooth"})
    e.preventDefault();
})
```