# Set scroll speed of OwlCarousel2

Tags: jquery, scroll, owl-carousel, mousewheel, owl-carousel-2

i've used a demo
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html
only changed code below because it make reverse scroll in that sample.

```
if (e.deltaY>0) {
owl.trigger('prev.owl');
} else {
owl.trigger('next.owl');
}
```

But it scrolls it with a very big speed.
if you use 6 items per stage - it's ok, but if you use like me 2 or 1 items per stage - it scroll me through to numbers 10-11, not to item numbers 3 or 4.

How i can make scroll speed slow? To scroll 2-3 items at one scroll?

I use Safari, Mac OSX Sierra

full JS code:

```
var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
loop:false,
// stagePadding: 100,
slideBy:1,
nav:true,
margin:0,
responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
0:{items:1},
600:{items:2,slideBy:2},
1024:{items:2,slideBy:2},
1366:{items:3,slideBy:3},
1920:{items:4,slideBy:4}
}
});

jQuery(".owl-prev").html('');
jQuery(".owl-next").html('');

owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
if (e.deltaY>0) {
owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [1000]);
} else {
owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [1000]);
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: to understand what i want - try resize window to the smallest size (one slide per stage) and try to scroll the owl carousel with mouse wheel
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html
you can't scroll by 1 slide or 2 - it scrolls 7-11 slides at once, it doesn't stop on slide 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you have to put the prev.owl.carousel up for example:

```
    owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
     if (e.deltaY>0) {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [5000]);
     } else {
      owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [5000]);
    }
```

e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: No, it doesn't help - it doesn't stop on numbers 3-4 it just VERY slowly scrolls to number 10-11 :)

Comment: There is similar question, but i'm not js coder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000111/smooth-horizontal-scroll-bound-to-mousewheel?rq=1